# Need help transforming some data with SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following postgres database table:

[image]

There are different actions at different timestamps. But here I only care about the actions START und END. For each START/END pair I want to have one row in my result table like so:

[image]

There is never an overlap between START-END intervals. So there is never two STARTs and then two ENDs for example.
Can anyone point me in the right direction how to wirte a query for that? I did not provide any SQL because I do not really know where to start and what language features to use.
Thanks!

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a self join with a twist: join all rows with `action = START` to the corresponding row with action = END where the timestamp is the smallest value that is bigger than the one with `action = START`.

This can be achieved using a lateral join:

```
select st."timestamp" as "start timestamp",
       en."timestamp" as "end timestamp"
from the_table st
  cross join lateral (
     select min(t2."timestamp") as "timestamp"
     from the_table t2
     where action = 'END'
      and t2."timestamp" > st."timestamp"
  ) en 
where st.action = 'START'
```

The cross join isn't really a cross join as the sub-query will never return more than one row.

Comment: Thank you, this was exaclty what I was looking for!